# Como crear una clase "global" en .Net Core 5

Tags: mvc, asp.net-core, singleton

Estoy diseñando una aplicacion en Net Core 5, despues de que el usuario se loguea muestro una ventana para seleccionar algunos datos todos son enteros (int), estos deben estar disponibles en toda la aplicacion.

No tengo mucha experiencia en Net Core, pero lo que he consultado, hablan de variables de Entorno o un patron Sigleton.

Hasta este momento no tengo ningun código escrito, porque no tengo idea de que hacer, cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar, se los agradeceria muchisimo.

Comment: usa una clase estatica...

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió la ayuda.